# gallery image to open in a selected page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, thumbnails

I have a thumbnail gallery, I want to open each big image in preview page with back links. Please suggest how may I do it.

the html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="big image link"><img src="thumb nail image"/></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="big image link"><img src="thumb nail image"/></a>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

want to open the big image in a preview page
the html

```
<div>
    <a href="back">Go back</a>
    <img src="holder for big image" />
</div>
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Why don't you use overlay's..

Comment: I do not want to use light box. try with jquery but does not work, me a novice in jquery, required your advice how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery, this will get you started:

html:

```
<div id="holder"></div>
<ul><li><img class="pointer" src="http://bit.ly/Yx18em"/></li></ul>
```

css:

```
#holder{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

li img{
    width:25px;
    height: auto;
}

.pointer{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

jquery:

```
$("ul img").click(function() {
  $('#holder').html(
      '<img src="'+$(this).attr('src') 
      +'"><span id="close" class="pointer">back</span>'
  ).show();
  $("#close").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().hide();
  });  
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qLEZ6/2/

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for the solution, but if I want to open thge image in a page with back button, this button will back the page to the gallery. Please advice

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want it to go to a complete new page, or just add a back button? I changed my code a bit, now there is a back button to close the big image. Is this what you need?

Comment: Daniel, I do little edit on your code but it not working...
http://jsfiddle.net/qLEZ6/3/

Comment: Hi, it didn't work because when you click the <a> tag de browser loads a new page with the img. I've added 'e.preventDefault();' in de code to prevent this. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/qLEZ6/6/ If this answers you question please accept my answer.

Comment: @user1292594 I'm glad I could help. Please close the question by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a plugin
[Photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/)

[this](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html) example demonstrates exactly what you looking for.